# Is it possible to show the percentage of completed task in the Timeline in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project, tasks, timeline

I am using Microsoft Project 2013.

I would like to visualize in the *Timeline* the percentage of completed task, for example 33%...

[image: timeline]

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the percentage of completed task to the timeline boxes. Other  option would be to manually color the tasks based of some criteria (not started, started, finished).

[image: Timeline a,b,c]

Answer (score 0):

Create a Gnatt chart in MS project first. you'll need to add the Gantt Chart Wizard to the Project ribbon. Click File > Options > Customize Ribbon. Click the tab where you put the wizard, and then click Gantt Chart Wizard. Follow the steps to create your new chart.

Right click on the Gantt chart to show the shortcut menu. Select "Bar Styles" from the shortcut menu to show the Bar Styles dialog. In the list of tasks - select "Project Summary" Click the "Text" tab in the lower portion of the dialog and select the "% Complete" field from the list where you want the value to appear.

For example, to show a task as 25 completed, click Task > 25% Complete. To see the task progress, point to the dark line inside the bar.